# Messaging Feature in webapp

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I want to make a private messaging system in my app, where a user logs in to his dashboard and gets an inbox and sent items, What would be the best approach to create such kind of a feature in the webapp?

Comment: Is not just like a stackoverflow question question....

Comment: Your question is likely way to broad. Do you have a user system in place for your app already and you just want to bolt on user messaging? Do you need that as well? If can add much more detail about what you are looking for that would help us guide you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're asking is too broad, but just in case I will assume you have a user system in place already where users can login

A pretty simple messaging system might look like this:

```
Messages {
    id : uuid
    to_user_id : int (if user_id is an integer in your system)
    from_user_id : int
    subject : text(255)
    message : text(10000)
    message_sent: datetime
    is_read : bit / bool
    is_deleted : bit / bool
}
```

Then you have two basic operations:

Show messages / read messages:

My Inbox: `SELECT * FROM Messages where to_user_id = %MY_USERID% and is_deleted = false`

My Sent:  `SELECT * FROM Messages where from_user_id = %MY_USERID%`

My Trash: `SELECT * FROM Messages where to_user_id = %MY_USERID% and is_deleted = true`

To send a new message you would create a record in the database and populate the appropriate fields..

Comment: Thanks Prescott, this is what i wanted..